# Warning VSP2005 & Error VSP1048 when instrumenting C++ code dynamically linked to FFMPEG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg, instrumentation

I am trying to profile my project with the Instrumentation profiler of Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I have a 64bit C++ project which is dynamically linked to FFMPEG. However, the profiler is giving me the following error `Error VSP1048: Internal instrumentation error`. I don't want to profile FFMPEG but only analyze the performance of my code. I downloaded the pre-built FFMPEG libs from this site [ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). The project is also linking against Boost, live555 and x264. It is running and debugging fine. The full output of the profiler is:

```
Profiling started.
Instrumenting ...\Player.exe in place
Info VSP3049: Small functions will be excluded from instrumentation.
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 12.0.21005 x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
Warning VSP2005: Internal instrumentation warning: The object '...\ffmpeg-20150506-git-a2190de-win64-dev\lib\avutil.lib(dbyqh.o)' was built without debug information.
File to Process:
\Player.exe --> ...\Player.exe
Original file backed up to ...\Player.exe.orig
Warning VSP2005: Internal instrumentation warning: The object '...\ffmpeg-20150506-git-a2190de-win64-dev\lib\avutil.lib(dbyqh.o)' was built without debug information.
Error VSP1048: Internal instrumentation error.
PRF0002: Instrumentation failed with these options: /u "...\Player.exe"   /excludesmallfuncs.  Please check the output window for additional details.
Data written to ...\Player150506.vsp.
Profiling finished.
File contains no data buffers
File contains no data buffers
Analysis failed
Profiling complete.
```

Any ideas how this could be solved? I have found very little about this issue on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  I was able to get some useful data by using the CPU Usage tool, rather than CPU Instrumentation.